# My application stopped launching with google_mobile_ads: ^0.13.0 package flutter

Tags: flutter, admob

Launching lib/main.dart on sdk gphone arm64 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
✓  Built build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app-debug.apk.
Installing build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app.apk...
E/AndroidRuntime(22444): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(22444): Process: com.n3t0l0b0.blogspot.mpc.view.lite, PID: 22444
E/AndroidRuntime(22444): **java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/reward/RewardedVideoAdListener;**
E/AndroidRuntime(22444):    at com.shatsy.admobflutter.AdmobFlutterPlugin.(Unknown Source:0)
E/AndroidRuntime(22444):    at com.shatsy.admobflutter.AdmobFlutterPlugin.registerWith(Unknown Source:0)
E/AndroidRuntime(22444):    at io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java:18)
E/AndroidRuntime(22444):    at com.n3t0l0b0.blogspot.mpc.view.lite.MainActivity.configureFlutterEngine(MainActivity.kt:13)
E/AndroidRuntime(22444):    at io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate.onAttach(FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate.java:180)
E/AndroidRuntime(22444):    at io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity.onCreate(FlutterActivity.java:409)
E/AndroidRuntime(22444):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8000)
E/AndroidRuntime(22444):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7984)
E/AndroidRuntime(22444):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)
E/AndroidRuntime(22444):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3422)
E/AndroidRuntime(22444):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)
E/AndroidRuntime(22444):    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
E/AndroidRuntime(22444):    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
E/AndroidRuntime(22444):    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
E/AndroidRuntime(22444):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
E/AndroidRuntime(22444):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
E/AndroidRuntime(22444):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
E/AndroidRuntime(22444):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
E/AndroidRuntime(22444):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(22444):    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
E/AndroidRuntime(22444):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
E/AndroidRuntime(22444): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.ads.reward.RewardedVideoAdListener" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~a29NxUkt4Kiz-H0rHByzQw==/com.n3t0l0b0.blogspot.mpc.view.lite-P6AM1rmvTmJmN96iEUwOkQ==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~a29NxUkt4Kiz-H0rHByzQw==/com.n3t0l0b0.blogspot.mpc.view.lite-P6AM1rmvTmJmN96iEUwOkQ==/lib/arm64, /data/app/~~a29NxUkt4Kiz-H0rHByzQw==/com.n3t0l0b0.blogspot.mpc.view.lite-P6AM1rmvTmJmN96iEUwOkQ==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /system_ext/lib64]]
E/AndroidRuntime(22444):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:207)
E/AndroidRuntime(22444):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
E/AndroidRuntime(22444):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
E/AndroidRuntime(22444):    ... 21 more
Error connecting to the service protocol: failed to connect to http://127.0.0.1:64017/1GFjUO3RNRw=/

Answer (score 1):

I found solution, i just removed the package **admob_flutter: ^1.0.1** from my pubspec.yaml

Answer (score 0):

It will resolve the issue by adding the correct "AdMob app ID" in the ApplicationManifest.xml file. Example code snippet given below

```
<manifest>
    <application>
        <!-- Sample **AdMob App ID**: ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713 -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx~yyyyyyyyyy"/>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

The documentation (https://pub.dev/packages/google_mobile_ads) clearly mentioned that "incorrect value will lead into application crash."

Official Documentation said that "The AdMob App ID must be included in the AndroidManifest.xml. Failure to do so will result in a crash on launch of an app."